# SQL Query to determine VAT rate

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm looking to create a 3 column VAT_Parameter table with the following columns:

```
VATID, VATRate, EffectiveDate
```

However, I can't get my head around how I would identify which vat rate applies to an invoice date.

for example if the table was populated with:

```
1, 17.5, 1/4/1991
2, 15, 1/1/2009
3, 20, 4/1/2011
```

Say for example I have an invoice dated 4/5/2010, how would an SQL query select the correct VAT rate for that date?

Answer (score 2):

```
select top 1 *
from VatRate
where EffectiveDate<=@InvoiceDate
order by EffectiveDate desc
```

Or, with a table of invoices

```
select id, invoicedate, rate
from
(
    select 
        inv.id, inv.invoicedate, vatrate.rate, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by inv.id order by vatrate.effectivedate desc) rn
    from inv
        inner join vatrate
            on inv.invoicedate>=vatrate.effectivedate
) v     
where rn = 1
```

PS. The rules for the rate of VAT to be charged when the rate changes are more complicated than just the invoice date. For example, the date of supply also matters.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this kind of thing before.  There are two choices I can think of:

**1.** Expand the table to have two dates: EffectiveFrom and EffectiveTo.  (You'll have to have a convention about whether each of these is exclusive or inclusive - but that's always a problem when using dates).  This raises the problem of validating that the table population, as a whole, makes sense.  e.g. that you don't end up with one row with Rate1 effective from 1/1/2000-1/1/2002, and another (overlapping) with Rate2 effective from 30/10/2001-1/1/2003.  Or an uncovered gap in time, where no rate applies.  Since this sounds like a very slowly-changing table, populated occasionally (by people who know what they're doing?), this could be the best solution.  The SQL to get the effective rate would then be simple:

```
SELECT VATRate FROM VATTable WHERE (EffectiveFrom<=[YourInvoiceDate]) AND (EffectiveTo>=[YourInvoiceDate])
```

or

**2.** Use your existing table structure, and use some slightly more complicated SQL to determine the effective rate for an invoice.

Using your existing structure, something like this would work:

```
SELECT VATTAble.VATRate FROM
    VATTable
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Max(EffectiveDate) AS LatestDate FROM VATTable WHERE EffectiveDate<= 
    YourInvoiceDate) latest
ON VATTable.EffectiveDate=latest.LatestDate
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier option may just be to denormalise your data structure and store the VAT rate in the invoice table itself.